# Proper display of unicode characters in desktop notifications

Tags: 20.04, notification, unicode

In the desktop notifications I receive (thunderbird, discord...), the smileys and unicode characters don't display properly.
The most annoying is that unicode characters for French are not supported. For example I receive `&#39;` instead of the character `'`. Is there a way to enable unicode and smiley support for desktop notification in ubuntu 20?
Thanks for your answers.